# BlackDesertOnline - Upgrade barricade

Tags: black-desert-online

In Black Desert Online you can upgrade barricades in NodeWars, how and what is needed for this?

I have checked the BDO forums and youtube but I cant find what is needed to upgrade the barricades

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after checking in game (via the players) it turns out it is 10 Iron Ingots and 5 Copper Shards to upgrade a barricade.

**Edit:** It appears the upgrade cost scales with the node level you are attacking.

- A level 1 node costs 10 Iron Ingots and 5 Copper Shards
- A level 2 node costs 10 Iron and 15 Copper Shards
- A level 3 (yet to be tried)

Confirmed through NodeWar, screenshot attached

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking at this after Feb 2017, it is now 30 Iron Ingot and 15 copper shard PER barricade upgrade.

Comment: For each node level? or for all node levels?